# Laravel Error Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've tried fixes for this error and nothing work. I upload a Laravel project to 000webhost. Error is showing when I try to get data from the database

API URL: https://ws-backend.000webhostapp.com/api/articles/0

Error

> Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7 (SQL: select * from
>   `articles` order by `created_at` desc limit 5 offset 0)

[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvDn9.png)

My query code

```
 public function get($start){
    $articles = Article::skip($start)->take(5)->latest()->get();
    return response()->json([
        'articles'=> $articles
    ]);

}
```

My config/database.php file

```
<?php
```

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        ‘options’ => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,],
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

];

.ENV FILE

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id6142552_ws
DB_USERNAME=id6142552_kikoos1
DB_PASSWORD=Kiko5678
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

000webhost not support value from .env file so you have to specify each value by your self in /confing/database.php

in database.php

```
'default' => 'mysql',
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'id6142552_ws',
        'username' => 'id6142552_kikoos1',
        'password' => 'Kiko5678',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true],
    ],
```

or if your code already working before then just add

```
'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true],
```

in mysql array